# Как сделать leaderboard с бд json? discord.py

Tags: python, json, discord.py

Я пытаюсь сделать топ 10 по монетам в своем боте. Я не знаю как это можно сделать, поэтому я обратился сюда, я не пытался что-либо писать просто я не знаю как и что. Так вот. У меня монеты юзера - это **money["тут айди пользователя"]["тут кол-во монет"]**. Кто не понял:

`{"676744847844897979": 0, "5465756846894984": 10}`

И мне нужно вывести топ 10 от самого большого до самого маленького.
Помогите пожалуйста, я новичок в этом деле.

Comment: Скиньте код, где Вы получаете пользователей.

Comment: лучше уж sqlite3 для такого дела

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, можно произвести сортировку путем перебора элементов словаря.
Как итог, получим новый словарь `top`, значения и ключи в котором будут отсортированы.

```
import json

money = {
    "id0": 38,
    "id1": 128,
    "id2": 184,
    "id3": 32,
    "id4": 30,
    "id5": 16,
    "id6": 185,
    "id7": 146,
    "id8": 53,
    "id9": 196
}

top_values = []
top_ids = []
top = {}
for id in money:
    top_values.append(money[id])
    top_ids.append(id)

for i in range(len(top_values)):
    for j in range(len(top_values)):
        if top_values[i] > top_values[j]:
            temp = top_values[i]
            top_values[i] = top_values[j]
            top_values[j] = temp

            temp = top_ids[i]
            top_ids[i] = top_ids[j]
            top_ids[j] = temp

for i in range(len(top_values)):
    if i < 10:
        top[top_ids[i]] = top_values[i]

print(json.dumps(top, ensure_ascii = False, indent = 4))
```

**Вывод:**

```
{
    "id9": 196,
    "id6": 185,
    "id2": 184,
    "id7": 146,
    "id1": 128,
    "id8": 53,
    "id0": 38,
    "id3": 32,
    "id4": 30,
    "id5": 16
}
```

---

Код можно улучшить или сократить, но эта версия тоже неплохо работает